# SET variables in batch file using FOR command

Tags: variables, batch-file, for-loop, environment-variables

I have a .bat file with the following commands.

My aim is concatenate the CLASSPATH variable value with the values of %%1.

The three first commands (outside of FOR command) concatenate the CLASSPATH correctly, but the FOR command only do it with the last value of the iteration.

Please help

```
    SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;test1.jar
    SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;test2.jar
    SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;test3.jar

    FOR %%1 IN ("%CXFHOME%\lib\*.jar") DO SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%%1
```

Comment: `... do set %%1`? syntax is: `set var=value`

Comment: Sorry, I have rewrite it

Answer (score 4):

You need delayed expansion:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%1 IN ("%CXFHOME%\lib\*.jar") DO SET CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%1
echo %classpath:~1%
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) for explanation and demonstration of delayed expansion.

Answer (score 1):

use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` in your script , the reason why concatenation is happening for last value of for loop is , for loop is taken as single instruction at run time so , all the values are replaced and the last values is only reflected.